# returning null if literal is empty

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

selecting first and last name with middle initial, if there is one, but I also need to select null if entire literal is empty,.  The current code is returning the spaces if the literal is empty, and that is messing up selection from view .

```
t1.first
      || ' '
      || NVL2 (t1.middle, t1.middle || ' ', NULL)
      || t1.last
         "SUPERVISOR"
```

This is taken from the select list, and everything is working except for when the entire literal selection is empty, then it is returning the spaces instead of NULL.  With this code, there are no NULL fields, and there should be a few NULLs.

Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine using a case statement would work.  You might have to tweak the conditions as I'm not sure if the values are null or empty strings.

```
CASE 
WHEN t1.first is null and t1.last is null and t1.middle is null 
THEN null
ELSE t1.first
          || ' '
          || NVL2 (t1.middle, t1.middle || ' ', NULL)
          || t1.last end 
             "SUPERVISOR"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the built string in a call to TRIM(), which will remove the blanks and return NULL if that's all that's there.  Here it is illustrated and proved by using NVL to detect if it is null and returning a value instead:

```
with tbl as
(
  select 'first' firstname, 'M' middlename, 'Last' lastname from dual
  union
  select NULL firstname, NULL middlename, NULL lastname from dual
)  
select NVL(trim(firstname || ' ' || middlename || ' ' || lastname), 'NO NAME ENTERED') fullname from tbl;


FULLNAME       
---------------
first M Last   
NO NAME ENTERED
```